# how to Use the client ID and client secret to obtain an access token using the OAuth 2.0 protocol

Tags: api, google-oauth

how to Use the client ID and client secret to obtain an access token using the OAuth 2.0 protocol

please give me an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also get token via ajax run this code in php file

```
<p id="demo"></p>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Request data</button>
```

Request data

```
<script>
function loadDoc() {
  const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
  }
  xhttp.open("POST", "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token");
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send("code=<?=$_REQUEST['code']?>&client_id=your_client_id&client_secret=your_client_secret&redirect_uri=your_redriction_url&grant_type=authorization_code");
}
</script>
```

Comment: you are a new but your explanation is owosom